# Offset Between ::after Element and Parent on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I'm encountering an issue with the positioning of the ::after pseudo-element relative to its parent element when scrolling. Here's the scenario:

When the width of the screen is greater than the width of the text, everything works as expected, and the ::after element fills the parent element correctly as the user scrolls. However, when the width of the screen is smaller than the width of the text, I notice that the ::after element has an offset and does not fill the parent element at the same position as the text, resulting in misalignment.

To mitigate this issue, I tried setting width: max-content to the parent element, which does resolve the alignment problem. However, this causes the text to overflow the screen.

I've experimented with different approaches to address this, but I haven't found a satisfactory solution yet. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this offset and alignment issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .fill {
            font-size: 3rem;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #003049;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            width: fit-content;
        }

        .fill::after {
            content: attr(data-text);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: #003049; 
            width: var(--width, 0);
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap; 
            transition: width .6s; 
        }

        #accueil {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="accueil">
        <h3 id="text" class="fill" data-text="Hi, this is a text fill animation">Hi, this is a text fill animation</h3>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper auctor nibh, id ultricies massa. Etiam fringilla lectus non viverra blandit. Ut ornare elit dolor, eget ultricies neque dapibus ac. Quisque mollis neque sit amet dui tincidunt, sed volutpat tellus ultricies. Quisque ut pulvinar arcu. Ut vitae nisi sem. Nullam ultrices a lorem at porta. Aliquam et nulla in nibh hendrerit convallis. Etiam nisi turpis, viverra vel iaculis sit amet, ornare pulvinar sapien.

            Suspendisse at imperdiet elit. Nullam nec suscipit magna. Praesent non rutrum orci. Duis facilisis magna vel sapien blandit sodales. In et sem vel magna euismod vulputate. Duis nibh ex, interdum sed scelerisque vitae, varius at diam. Duis sed purus quis risus sagittis elementum at ac lacus. Sed at leo blandit, pretium mauris non, tincidunt ex.

            Suspendisse consectetur finibus est nec posuere. Nullam rutrum leo dui, et ultrices mi tempus sit amet. Proin ullamcorper orci felis, eu elementum mi tempus sit amet. Nullam et lectus suscipit, feugiat ligula sit amet, condimentum magna. Proin vitae orci vitae purus auctor semper id a leo. Etiam et condimentum mi. Suspendisse lacinia eleifend turpis sit amet finibus. Morbi ultricies imperdiet libero.

            Integer quis egestas lectus. Quisque sem turpis, fringilla at purus ac, dictum luctus sem. Mauris efficitur dictum velit quis consectetur. Nulla posuere justo at pharetra egestas. Vivamus nulla ipsum, ornare vitae elementum quis, gravida eget velit. Mauris pellentesque vel massa vel fermentum. Suspendisse posuere arcu quis metus pretium, at mollis dolor cursus. Cras nec turpis mollis odio sodales suscipit. Nam luctus nibh sed augue gravida feugiat. Etiam egestas dictum mauris, non faucibus libero pharetra ut. Maecenas in sem et orci facilisis faucibus. Quisque quis euismod lorem, eu gravida sem. Nam eu tellus libero.

            Nunc vitae efficitur felis. Maecenas tellus sem, suscipit at laoreet sit amet, pretium non lorem. Integer at sem quis nisi molestie ultricies vitae ac eros. Fusce ac metus ex. Aliquam tempus ligula et lorem accumsan sodales. Phasellus finibus nibh ipsum, sed malesuada nulla blandit id. Phasellus sed pharetra quam, vel convallis ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In pharetra cursus viverra.
        </p>
    </section>

    <script>
        let textToAnimate = document.getElementById('text');
        let homeSection = document.getElementById('accueil');
        let topSection = homeSection.offsetTop;
        let topText = textToAnimate.offsetTop;
        let endAnimation = (topText - topSection) - 20;
        let bottomSection = topSection + homeSection.offsetHeight;
        let fillElement = document.querySelector('.fill');

        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
            let initialOffset = topSection - window.innerHeight;
            if(window.scrollY >= initialOffset) {

                for(let i = 0; i < endAnimation; i++ ) {
                    let coef = (window.scrollY - topSection) / endAnimation;
                    coef = Math.min(Math.max(coef, 0), 1);
                    fillElement.style.setProperty('--width', coef * 100 + '%');
                }

            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The headline text gets broken into _two_ lines here with the width of the rendered snippet - so using `white-space: nowrap;` on the pseudo filler element, _can't_ make any sense to begin with, if you want it to work in this situation as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a good start, but I dont know how to prevent my text from overlapping the screen

Comment: You could use media queries, to lower the font size, so that it won't break into multiple lines on narrower screens. If you want to allow it to break however, you will need a different approach than the current one.

Comment: Searching for other approach, thanks

Comment: You could use JS to find out the lines of text, and then deal with each one in turn. Messy because you’d need to remove the extra tags on any change to layout.